# "Mutex"-coordinated bus in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I'm developing an FPGA design in which a VGA display is driven. Within the top-level entity, an `rgb` signal contains a 12-bit vector describing the current pixel's colour.

Several shapes need to be drawn to the screen. Each shape has its own entity (`circle`, `rect`, etc.).
At the moment, each of these entites emits a `mask : std_logic` output which is '1' when this entity is providing a colour to the output rgb port, and '0' when the x and y co-ordinates fall outside of the shape's boundaries, and therefore no RGB output is provided.

I'm having difficulty coordinating this to avoid multiple driver issues. For example, I thought I could do the following:

- Within each shape entity, use the following:

  ```vhdl
  rgb_write : process(mask)
  begin
     if mask = '1' then
        rgb <= some_color;
     end if;
  end process;
  ```

  In this way, the rgb port wouldn't have a driver when the mask is 0, allowing other entities to drive the top-level signal.
  I also emit the mask output as previously mentioned, and use this in the top-level entity:

  ```vhdl
  -- mask_vec is a std_logic_vector which contains all masks from all shapes

  rgb_cleanup : process(mask_vec, rgb)
  begin
      if (or mask_vec = '0') then -- Note that this uses VHDL08 unary or
         rgb <= (others => '0');
      end if;
  end process;
  ```

  The above code (should) provide a black pixel whenever the pixel is not being driven by one of the entities.
  However, this doesn't work. GHDL is always reading rgb as invalid when I try to do a `to_integer(unsigned(rgb))` (for example).

How do I coordinate these shapes properly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no driver disabling going on here, nor would such be synthesis eligible  should you actually do driver disconnection. Each process that assigns a signal has a driver for that signal. A driver will retain the value last assigned. Use multiplexers which can be described as AND-OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this doesn't do what you think it does:

```vhdl
rgb_write : process(mask)
begin
   if mask = '1' then
      rgb <= some_color;
   end if;
end process;
```

Instead of leaving `rgb` "undriven" when `mask` is low, it creates a latch. `rgb` simply retains its previous value when the condition is false.

Besides which, what happens if two or more of your shapes overlap?

What you need is a priority encoder that takes all of the mask signals as inputs and produces a number that indicates which shape should be displayed at any given position, and then a multiplexer that selects the color for that shape.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRyIDg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output of U1 is a two-bit number indicating which mask input is active with the highest priority; it is zero if none of the inputs are active. Note that the shape generators don't need to actually output a color at all, just a mask signal. The colors can be assigned separately at the mux inputs.

In HDL, these can be combined into a single process. The `if` - `elsif` structure implements the priority encoder, and the assignment statements implement the mux.

```
process (mask_vec)
begin
  if    mask_vec(0) = '1' then rgb <= shape_0_color;
  elsif mask_vec(1) = '1' then rgb <= shape_1_color;
  elsif mask_vec(2) = '1' then rgb <= shape_2_color;
  else                         rgb <= background_color;
  end if;
end process;
```

Comment: How well does this design scale with an increase in shape entities?

Comment: In response to my own Q, fairly well using generics.